# Duplicate symbols with CocoaPods and SwiftPM

Tags: ios, cocoapods, swiftpm

Ever since Xcode11 we've been migrating from CocoaPods to SwiftPM.
Unfortunately some of the dependencies don't have SwiftPM support yet. [Like Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3136).

This isn't a real problem, since both of them can coexist next to eachother.
But since (I think Firebase iOS SDK v6.13.0) they added a dependency to `PromisesObjC`.
Which in itself isn't a problem, but most of our projects (and (sub)dependencies) use [promises by google](https://github.com/google/promises) through SwiftPm.

Now the problem is that both the **Promises** SwiftPM dependency and **Firebase** CocoaPods one uses **FBLPromises** and this will result in the following error:

```
duplicate symbol '_FBLPromiseRetryDefaultAttemptsCount' in:
    /path/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBLPromises.o
    /path/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Retry.o)
duplicate symbol '_FBLPromiseRetryDefaultDelayInterval' in:
    /path/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBLPromises.o
    /path/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Retry.o)
duplicate symbol '_FBLWaitForPromisesWithTimeout' in:
    /path/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBLPromises.o
    /path/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise+Testing.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBLPromise' in:
    /path/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBLPromises.o
    /path/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBLPromise' in:
    /path/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBLPromises.o
    /path/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
ld: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

Currently the only way to fix this is to set the **Firebase** CocoaPods depenceny to `v6.11.0`

My current **Podfile**:

```rb
source 'git@github.com:CocoaPods/Specs.git'

workspace 'Workspace'

platform :ios, '11.0'

use_modular_headers!
inhibit_all_warnings!

install! 'cocoapods',
    :generate_multiple_pod_projects => true,
    :incremental_installation => true

target 'HandpickedFamilyApp' do
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    pod 'Firebase/Performance'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'SwiftLint'

    script_phase :name => 'Run Fabric',
                :script => '"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"',
                :input_files => ['$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)']
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing my google search term 'cocoapods swiftpm duplicate symbols' with 'cocoapods carthage duplicate symbols' I came up with a similar problem with a different dependency.
And essentially forgot all about the `use_frameworks!` setting.

Adding this to my **Podfile** fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using `use_frameworks!` in the Podfile helps you get rid of the duplicate symbols error in the question, but this time I ended up with many warnings in my console:

> Class is implemented in both, One of the two will be used. Which one
> is undefined

After trying many things, I have solved these problems by installing both Firebase and Google AdMobs SDK via Cocoapods (without using Swift Package Manager).

1. Remove Firebase from the package dependencies
2. Edit your **Podfile** as follows:

   ```
    pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
    # Or, to not use AdId:
    # pod 'Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport'
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
   ```