# FBLPromise crash with CocoaPods and SwiftPM implemented in both

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, swiftpm

We've been migrating away from CocoaPods since a while, but not every dependency has made the switch. [Like Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3136).

I've had a similar question [regarding duplicate symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60002257/duplicate-symbols-with-cocoapods-and-swiftpm), but now I'm facing something new, which is probably because I'm using a dependency in both SwiftPM as in CocoaPods.

After running my (sample) project it crashes:

```
-[FBLPromise firebaseInstallationID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003f5a430
```

with a warning at the top:

```
objc[93047]: Class FBLPromise is implemented in both
/xxx/SampleProject.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises (0x10b3f09a8) and 
/xxx/SampleProject.app/SampleProject (0x10af736f0).
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Prior to my update to Firebase SDK v6.26.0 I would only get the first warning, but since the update it crashes.

I saw a doc about how to use [Firebase within libraries](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/docs/firebase_in_libraries.md) and a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5467) regarding a similar crash. But nothing seems to work to resolve this crash, other then downgrading.

I uploaded a sample project: https://github.com/basvankuijck/SampleProjectFirebaseCrash.

Removing the SwiftPM Promises dependency is not an option, since the actual project is using a SwiftPM dependency that has a dependency to Promises.

The [Podfile](https://github.com/basvankuijck/SampleProjectFirebaseCrash/blob/master/Podfile) is nothing that fancy, and the SampleProject just uses [one single SwiftPM dependency](https://github.com/basvankuijck/SampleProjectFirebaseCrash/blob/master/SampleProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved).

Anyone who has an idea how to let SwiftPM and CocoaPods play nicely together especially with Firebase in the middle?

Comment: Thoughts from Firebase team at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5855

Answer (score 6):

I faced the exact same problem with Firebase and FBLPromise. For me it arose because I added Firebase/FireStore in podfile but the rest of the FIrebase dependencies from SPM. Among my other SPM dependencies was FBLPromise as well.

To fix it I had to remove the FIrebase package from SPM and then add it again with FIrestore and other dependencies that I could need from Firebase.

No other solution worked for me.